# HTML/CSS issue: need an advice. How to

Tags: javascript, html, connection, flowchart

I'm creating somekind of flowchart builder on JS. I need an advice about how can I make two blocks (divs) connected with an arrow or line.
Look at the example below

```
 ______
|      |
|  DIV x----------------
|      |                |
--------                |
                        |
                      __x___
                     |      |
                     | DIV2 |
                     |      |
                     --------
```

Divs are dragable so the connection have to be dynamic. Can you help me guys with it?

Cheers

Comment: It's not possible with HTML. You need to use HTML5 Canvas API, but below IE9 browsers don't support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea;

Think the lines as a div also. Lets say it is divLine. divLine should have the background-color of the page. Then you can assign borders. So that it will seem like a line.

Whenever a user drags the other div, you check the X and Y values anyway. According to those values, resize your divLines's height,width and position. Probably you will have to change border values also.

Of course HTML 5 is the much better solution but it is not working in every browser.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rdwrX/  can be something like this. But you need JS coding for drag and drop options.